# R finding date intervals by ID

Tags: r, intervals, datediff

Having the following table which comprises  some key columns which are: customer ID | order ID | product ID | Quantity | Amount | Order Date.

All this data is in LONG Format, in that you will get multi line items for the 1 Customer ID.

I can get the first date last date using R DateDiff but converting the file to WIDE format using Plyr, still end up with the same problem of getting multiple orders by customer, just less rows and more columns.

Is there an R function that extends R DateDiff to work out how to get the time interval between purchases by Customer ID? That is, time between order 1 and 2, order 2 and 3, and so on assuming these orders exists.

```
CID     Order.Date  Order.DateMY    Order.No_    Amount Quantity  Category.Name    Locality
1       26/02/13    Feb-13          zzzzz                   1       r                 MOSMAN
1       26/05/13    May-13          qqqqq                   1       x               CHULLORA
1       28/05/13    May-13           wwwww                  1       r               MOSMAN
1       28/05/13    May-13           wwwww                  1       x                 MOSMAN
2       19/08/13    Aug-13          wwwwww                  1       o                OAKLEIGH SOUTH
3       3/01/13    Jan-13           wwwwww                  1       x                 CURRENCY CREEK
4       28/08/13    Aug-13         eeeeeee                  1       t                 BRISBANE
4       10/09/13    Sep-13         rrrrrrrrr                1       y               BRISBANE
4       25/09/13    Sep-13         tttttttt                 2       e               BRISBANE
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, like `dput(head(df))` where `df` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: oops sorry, forgot to add it in, just fixed it.

Comment: @digdeep You should add the expected result. Dor example, try to apply "That is, time between order 1 and 2, order 2 and 3" on the given data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the data frame and find the intervals for each Customer ID.

```
df <- data.frame(customerID=as.factor(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4))),
OrderDate=as.Date(c("2013-07-01","2013-07-02","2013-07-03","2013-06-01","2013-06-02",
"2013-06-03","2013-07-01")))

dfs <- split(df,df$customerID)
lapply(dfs,function(x){
tmp <-diff(x$OrderDate)
tmp
})
```

Or use `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
dfs <- dlply(df,.(customerID),function(x)return(diff(x$OrderDate)))
```

Comment: That still gives the first and last, I am trying to work out the time interval by number of orders. In your example, the 30 days for B, i am interested in Order 1 to order 2 for B is 1 day, order 2 to order 3 is 1 day, etc.. Also, worth adding, the data set I have is 500k rows.

Comment: Also, if you use data.table package, this is pretty neat. j = list (coverage = diff(range(Order.Date)),

Comment: I editted the answer and this should give you all the intervals. If it is a big data set, I don't know a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the plyr option Zhenglei, used the data.table version below as it was super quick

Comment: @Zhenglei The use of `diff` assume that your data is already ordered. and `lapply+split ~~ by`

Comment: @agstudy you are right and I think yours is a better answer to the  question. And I did not quite understand the last part.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what do you want to do since you don't give the expected result. But I guess you want to the the intervals between 2 orders.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, list(Order.Date,
          diff = c(0,diff(sort(as.Date(Order.Date,'%d/%m/%y')))) ),CID]

   CID Order.Date diff
1:   1   26/02/13    0
2:   1   26/05/13   89
3:   1   28/05/13    2
4:   1   28/05/13    0
5:   2   19/08/13    0
6:   3    3/01/13    0
7:   4   28/08/13    0
8:   4   10/09/13   13
9:   4   25/09/13   15
```

Comment: Spot on @agstudy that worked a treat (super quick too :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I just figured out another way to do it and wanted to record it:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(lubridate)
> df %>% group_by(customerID) %>% 
    mutate(SinceLast=(interval(ymd(lag(OrderDate)),ymd(OrderDate)))/86400)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   customerID [2]
  customerID OrderDate  SinceLast
  <fct>      <date>         <dbl>
1 A          2013-07-01       NA 
2 A          2013-07-02        1.
3 A          2013-07-03        1.
4 B          2013-06-01       NA 
5 B          2013-06-02        1.
6 B          2013-06-03        1.
7 B          2013-07-01       28.
```